VPN: Before "VpnName" may be linked, "AppName" must be modified by the developer
enter image description here
I am encountering an 'update required' issue with my VPN app that features Wireguard. Despite resolving all errors, ensuring compatibility with iOS 16.0, and configuring targets, Network Extension and app groups appropriately, I am still encountering this error in the Settings app.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

This is not a coding issue it's a configuration issue.

Thank you for the suggestion! My issue has been resolved now. I appreciate your help! @DavidBuck

1: Open your Xcode project.
2: Navigate to the project settings by selecting your project from the project navigator.
3: Choose the target for which you want to adjust the build phases. Targets are listed under the "Targets" section.
4: Click on the "Build Phases" tab.
5: Locate the section labeled "Copy Bundle Resources". This section manages the files that are copied into your app bundle.
6: Deselect the checkbox labeled "Copy Only When Installing" for the file you wish to exclude.
7: Save your changes.
enter image description here
